# How to provide hash of last git commit of a python package?

Tags: git, python-packaging, python-poetry

Is there a possibility to provide the hash value of the last git commit that the python package is based on? Ideally, I would like to be able to do something like this:

```py
import my_package as mp

print(mp.__git_hash__)
```

and receive the git commit hash (e.g. something like `770f67ec492d`). This would allow me to very specifically determine which version of the software was used. As the normal version number is not bumped for every commit and only bumped manually, I would like to have an automatic solution.

If possible, this solution should work for two use cases:

1. Having a local version of the python package installed, e.g. by cloning the git repo and running `pip install .` which installs the package via `poetry` in the current environment. When making updates to the code and commits, the new git commit hash should be available after a `pip install .`.
2. Installing the package via PyPI, where the git commit hash must have been included during the build process of `poetry` before it is published.

I think what I'm looking for is something like a hook in the build/installation process of poetry where I would be able to run my own small script and inject some meta information into the package before it is built/installed. Unfortunately, so far I haven't found a solution, but maybe someone already has and can give me a hint?

I found the possibility to run post-commit hooks which would enable receiving the commit hash and writing it to some file. Then the package could read it from there. However, this requires the git hooks to manually be set on every developer's development environment. Ideally, I am looking for an automatic solution where no developer has any extra work. More importantly, in the above solution the file with the hash value would not be part of the commit itself, i.e. not be version controlled. Therefore, having a hook during build/installation time within poetry might be the better solution.

Comment: Maybe https://pypi.org/project/poetry-dynamic-versioning/  or https://pypi.org/project/poetry-git-version-plugin/ -- Otherwise you can write your own Poetry plug-in